# Can't add items to my ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a three column ListView (the columns were defined using the Visual Studio designer) in a C# program which I'm trying to fill with data from another form, I tried to use this function which is located in the same class as the ListView (the Input class), but called from the click event of a button in another form (the HandleData class).

```
public void agregarALista(string label, string longitud,string cantidad)
{
   ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem(label);
   i.SubItems.Add(longitud);
   i.SubItems.Add(cantidad);
   listView1.Items.Add(i);
}
```

while debugging I can see it executes those lines, so the call is ok, but no data is added to  my listView1.

What do you think this may be?

Here's the calling function in the other form, located in the HandleData class:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Input agregarView = new Input();
   double dOutput = 0;
   if (Double.TryParse(textBox2.Text,out dOutput))
   {
      agregar.agregarLista(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);

      agregarView.agregarALista(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
      if (MessageBox.Show("Continuar agregando?","Otra orden", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
      {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
      }
      else
      {
         this.Dispose();
         this.Close();
      }
   }
   else
   {
     MessageBox.Show("No es una Longitud Valida");
     textBox2.Clear();
   }            
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `listView1.Refresh();`?

Comment: Could you post the code which sets up the list view?  Have you added columns to the listview before you attempt to add items?

Comment: Hi, I added the columns using the visual studio design editor, and even tried calling the function within the same class with hardcoded strings, and it worked, My real question would be, how can I call that function from another class, so that it'd be able to modify listView1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView's SubItems work only if you have defined Columns in the ListView and if you have ListView's View set to View.Details

```
// Set to details view.
listView1.View = View.Details;
// Add a column with width 20 and left alignment.
listView1.Columns.Add("longitud", 20, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("candidat", 20, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
//... and so on
```

Check this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/AddListViewcolumnandinsertListViewrows.htm) for a complete picture of how to add columns programmatically and populate with subitems (it also uses ListView.BeginUpdate() and ListView.EndUpdate() methods which prevent redrawing the listview everytime you add an item in multiple add item operation).

**UPDATE:**
To be able to update the listView1 of Form 1 due to adding ListViewItems in Form 2, you need to create and event in Form 2 (adding of ListViewItems) and handle this event in Form 1 (eventhandler).
Check this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077677/add-to-listview-from-another-form) for more details.

Comment: Hi, I added the columns using the visual studio design editor, and even tried calling the function within the same class with hardcoded strings, and it worked, My real question would be, how can I call that function from another class, so that it'd be able to modify listView1?

Comment: Ah! For that you need to create an event in your 2nd form and create an eventhandler for this event in your 1st form. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077677/add-to-listview-from-another-form)

Comment: +1, I spent a lot of time to find resolving the "can't insert items into ListView" problem, my code seem perfectly, but when I see your answer, I know I lacked this line: listView1.View = View.Details;